# remove rows based on multiple columns values in awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to remove rows based on 4th column value is equal to 7 and 5th column value less than 30 from my text file using awk.

Here is my text file

```
1 1 2017 7 00 00 95.197469 112.803277    
1 1 2017 7 05 00 94.139040 113.255244  
1 1 2017 7 10 00 93.084220 113.715022  
1 1 2017 7 15 00 92.033141 114.182867  
1 1 2017 7 20 00 90.985940 114.659045  
1 1 2017 7 25 00 89.500772 115.143830  
1 1 2017 7 30 00 88.574990 115.637504  
1 1 2017 7 35 00 87.614221 116.140360  
1 1 2017 7 40 00 86.633495 116.652701  
1 1 2017 7 45 00 85.642547 117.174839  
1 1 2017 7 50 00 84.647055 117.707097  
1 1 2017 7 55 00 83.650410 118.249809  
1 1 2017 8 00 00 82.654745 118.803319  
1 1 2017 8 05 00 81.661486 119.367982  
1 1 2017 8 10 00 80.671646 119.944164  
1 1 2017 8 15 00 79.685987 120.532243  
1 1 2017 8 20 00 78.705118 121.132609  
1 1 2017 8 25 00 77.729550 121.745662  
1 1 2017 8 30 00 76.759731 122.371816  
1 1 2017 8 35 00 75.796072 123.011494  
1 1 2017 8 40 00 74.838956 123.665132  
1 1 2017 8 45 00 73.888755 124.333179  
1 1 2017 8 50 00 72.945832 125.016092  
1 1 2017 8 55 00 72.010551 125.714342  
1 1 2017 9 00 00 71.083276 126.428408
```

Comment: Also please be clear in your questions and requirements what is needed exactly.

Comment: See [ask] before posting another question. I'm amazed you got any answers to this.

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '$4!=7 || $5>=30 {print}' file
```

Output:

```
1 1 2017 7 30 00 88.574990 115.637504  
1 1 2017 7 35 00 87.614221 116.140360  
1 1 2017 7 40 00 86.633495 116.652701  
1 1 2017 7 45 00 85.642547 117.174839  
1 1 2017 7 50 00 84.647055 117.707097  
1 1 2017 7 55 00 83.650410 118.249809  
1 1 2017 8 00 00 82.654745 118.803319  
1 1 2017 8 05 00 81.661486 119.367982  
1 1 2017 8 10 00 80.671646 119.944164  
1 1 2017 8 15 00 79.685987 120.532243  
1 1 2017 8 20 00 78.705118 121.132609  
1 1 2017 8 25 00 77.729550 121.745662  
1 1 2017 8 30 00 76.759731 122.371816  
1 1 2017 8 35 00 75.796072 123.011494  
1 1 2017 8 40 00 74.838956 123.665132  
1 1 2017 8 45 00 73.888755 124.333179  
1 1 2017 8 50 00 72.945832 125.016092  
1 1 2017 8 55 00 72.010551 125.714342  
1 1 2017 9 00 00 71.083276 126.428408
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more concise `awk`

*Removing line where field 4 equals 7 **and** field 5 less than 30*

```
$ awk '!($4==7 && $5<30)' case_file_48485025
```

*Output*

```
1 1 2017 7 30 00 88.574990 115.637504  
1 1 2017 7 35 00 87.614221 116.140360  
1 1 2017 7 40 00 86.633495 116.652701  
1 1 2017 7 45 00 85.642547 117.174839  
1 1 2017 7 50 00 84.647055 117.707097  
1 1 2017 7 55 00 83.650410 118.249809  
1 1 2017 8 00 00 82.654745 118.803319  
1 1 2017 8 05 00 81.661486 119.367982  
1 1 2017 8 10 00 80.671646 119.944164  
.
.
```

**How it works**

- By default `awk` prints a line if it sees a non-zero value as its command
- `!($4==7 && $5<30)` would evaluate to zero when your condition is met and hence `awk` doesn't print.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^.........7.[0-2]/d' file
```

Delete a line that has a `7` in the 4th column and `0` to `2` as the first character of the 5th column.